# Помогите разобраться, где ошибка Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math 
x=90 
Pi=3.14 
RAD=90 
ta=math.tan(math.radians(X)) 
Formula=2*Pi*RAD*ta 
print(Formula)
```

Comment: Нужно в строке  ta=math.tan(math.radians(x))  написать x  строчной буквой, а не заглавной

Answer (score 5):

1. Как уже другие сказали, у вас переменная `x`, а не `X`.
2. Модуль `math` определяет число «пи» более точно, чем вы — используйте `math.pi`.
3. То, чего вы хотите сделать, *бессмысленно*, так как значение тангенс 90<sup>o</sup> *неопределенно* — оно стремится к положительной бесконечности, значит, вы получите какое-то *очень большое число, не имеющего никакого значения.*
4. Но и ваша `Formula` *еще более бессмысленна*, т.к вы в ней умножаете радианы на градусы, не говоря о том, что даже умножение градусов на градусы или радианов на радианы не имеет смысла.

Comment: Умножая градусы на градусы получим стерадиан, он же квадратный градус. В них измеряются телесные углы. Площадь созвездия, например.

Comment: @Эникейщик, интересно. Какой телесный угол соответствует `pi*pi` или `(pi/2)*(pi/3)` или даже `(11*pi)*(-15*pi)`?

Comment: Я уверен, что вам не требуется посторонняя помощь в перемножении двух числе.

Comment: @Эникейщик, в перемножении двух числе нет, но я хочу *видеть* такие телесные углы — например угол со значением `-165*pi^2` стерадианов. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что такой угол существует и вы можете его увидеть? Нарисуйте мне квадрат со стороной -6i, или хотя бы просто -6, тогда, может быть, у вас получится увидеть такой телесный угол. Детский сад какой-то, в самом деле.

Comment: @Эникейщик, мне кажется, что вы не поняли иронию. Вы утверждаете, что имеет смысл умножить радианы на радианы. Я вам говорю, что нет. Угол `-15*pi` действительно существует. Угол `11*pi` тоже. Но их произведение не имеет смысла. Нет такого телесного угла.

Comment: Ну хорошо, покажите мне угол -15пи. Настоящий, а не спираль в координатах.

Comment: @Эникейщик, я не хочу с вами спорить на философическом уровне. Всё, что я хотел сказать, уже сказал. Не буду вам мешать умножать угол на угол, когда вам это нравится, но я этого делать не буду. Я старался объяснить, почему, ну, не получилось.

Comment: Удивительное дело. Когда вы просите меня предъявить продукт ваших фантазий, то это ирония. А когда я прошу вас показать то, что по вашим словам существует, это вдруг стало философией.